# Mobile safari page zooms in when page width changes

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, meta, pinchzoom

I'm working on a web application that is meant to run on mobile safari.  When certain functions of the program are active, the page zooms in, forcing the user to pinch zoom out to see the entirety of the content.  I'm using the meta tag that is meant to control zooming on my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `user-scalable=no`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 ,user-scalable=no">
```

> Determines whether or not the user can zoom in and out—whether or not the user can change the scale of the viewport. Set to yes to allow scaling and no to disallow scaling. The default is yes.

[developer.apple.com - Meta Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW7)

Comment: Unfortunately. this does not solve my problem as I don't think the scale is changing, rather the width of the website.  Also, regardless of this tag, the user is able to zoom out so that the viewport is filled by the content.